# How I can check array length from google cloud firestore For Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an Android app and want to check array length in Cloud Firestore. I have tried many times but could not find a solution. Can you help me?

edited below:

I want to get the size of the array that which user favorited it. Below is my array in Firestore. Also, I can access document II, because I save it when It is created first.
[firestore screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAZxl.jpg)

The code which I get fail is below:
[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2QSU.jpg)

I really tried many times but cannot get size of array.

Comment: Please edit the question to post the code that you tried that isn't working the way you expect, along with your debugging observations.  You will need to read the document and query the array for its size.  We can't tell what part of that is the problem in your case.

Comment: I have added more information. Sorry for delaying and missing detail first.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your question, you need to read the size of the `favoriteUser` array that exists in all documents that are returned by your query. In this case, most likely you should use a simple get() call rather than reading the data in real-time. So the simplest solution would be:

```
val query = Firebase.firestore.collection("Created").whereEqualTo(someId)
query.get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        for (doc in it.result) {
            val obj = doc.getData()["favoriteUser"]
            if(obj != null) {
                val arraySize = (obj as List<String>).size
                Log.d("TAG", "$arraySize")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that [DocumentSnapshot#getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData()) returns an object of type [`Map<String, Object>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html), so that's the reason why we can read the content inside it.

Comment: Good to hear that, nicksizadam.

Comment: So can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest. Thanks to you, my problem has been solved.